# How to expose custom type with JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8

I have a database implemented in C++ that stores some custom data types.
I'm now working on a JDBC driver for this database (Java 8 if it matters). I reimplemented the C++ custom types in Java. Serializing and deserializing works fine, the only remaining question is what is the correct way for a JDBC driver to expose such a type?

`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()` and `DatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo()` and  will have to return some constant and I found two promising ones: [`OTHER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html#OTHER) and [`JAVA_OBJECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html#JAVA_OBJECT)

Actually, I tested both of these types already with [SQirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and neither of them works. For `JAVA_OBJECT` it displays `"Unknown type"` for all entries in a column and for `OTHER` it displays `"OTHER"`. I could only make it work by declaring my type as `NVARCHAR` and return its String representation.

Is this an issue with SQirreL or am I supposed to expose my type differently?

Also, as I literally cannot find anything on this topic, I'm wondering if there will be any existing clients that support custom types?

If no, I should likely declare them as an `NVARCHAR` and return its String representation instead.

Comment: There is no `DatabaseMetaData.getColumnType()` do you mean `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()`? For the latter the correct way (I think) is to return `Types.OTHER` and then return the correct name with `getColumnTypeName()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are absolutely right. I mixed that up with `getTypeInfo()`. Fixed, thanks. But that was just a typo in my question. It still doesn't work with SQuirreL. So, it's bug there and I should go that way?

Comment: Sorry I don't use SQuirrel. But you should only return `Types.JAVA_OBJECT` if your custom type is indeed a serialized instance of a Java class. Otherwise use `Types.OTHER`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, that is very valuable information. But are you aware of any clients that work this way? Because even if this is the correct way, if (almost) no client supports the correct way, it has no value for me...

Comment: Work which way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I declare my type to be `Types.OTHER`, I expect a client to not show "OTHER". E.g. I just tested DB Visualizer, that "works" by calling `toSTring()` on the custom type

Comment: If the column type is `Types.OTHER` the SQL client should absolutely display `OTHER` - what else should it do if it doesn't know the real name?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I meant the content of the column, not the type name. DB Visualizer certainly calls `toString()` on my custom type, which is nice because it has a human readable String representation. SQirreL, for built-in types like `java.sql.Timestamp`, also seems to make use of `toString()` for displaying purposes. But for my custom type, however, it doesn't. Instead it shows an entire column full of "OTHER"